# Accidentaly deleted /etc/X11/xorg.conf.original, and now log in no longer works

Tags: drivers, ati, xorg, fglrx

I accidentally deleted xorg.conf.original-0; xorg.conf.fglrx xorg.conf.fglrx-0-1, after I tried to install fglrx drivers on the graphics card, which in fact worked on 13.04 and now as I went to 13.10 has not worked.

```
      Now I can just switch to a new TTY with:  Ctrl + Alt + F2
```

[I found this which is for nVidia cards](http://analogbit.com/fix_nvidia_edid)

TO install the fglrx drivers for graphic card [I used this tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/286775#286775)

Is there any possibility that I can recover, replace, rebuilb that xorg.conf.original-0, and if exists any possibility where I could start from.

Comment: If you can't find the files on the web, when the login screen comes in (if any) press `Ctrl+Alt+F1` to get dropped to a tty, log in as root and reinstall whatever you thing it's necessary (the X server, I guess) using `apt-get purge package-name&&apt-get install package-name`. Or log in your normal user and use `sudo`, if you don't have the root password.

Comment: thank you for the advice but still does not work, I try this commands `sudo service lightdm stop`; `dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg`, `sudo service lightdm start`

Comment: And also I tried reinstaling the xserver                        `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First terminate the X using:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/gdm stop
```

Then reconfigure you're driver using:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

And restart GUI:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/gdm start
```

Answer (score 0):

finally I managed to make GUI with this complete guide([Fix catalyst driver in Ubuntu 13.04 / 13.10](http://xpressrazor.wordpress.com/2013/05/31/fix-catalyst-driver-in-ubuntu-13-04/)), but now there's another problem:
When I try to enter my password and login to Unity (normal without `ctrl+alt+f1`), is triyng to enter the Unity user interface but with no result(black screen) and kicks me out again to login screen.

I said I fix the problem because I can connect in Unity only with `ctrl + alt + f1` then `sudo startx` command.

Comment: so my question now is there a way that i can auto start xorg to  login my account, so i dont have to type startx. thanks.

Comment: really can not give anyone an advice where I could turn, I have nearly three weeks since I have not solved this problem and is quite annoying to start with `sudo startx` always...I've been looking but I did not found anything that might help